# Cloud Functions for Firebase return array of promises to GCF

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

In my `onWrite` event handler I perform data updates in different database paths. The function gets interrupted without finishing performing tasks. I am implementing `Promise.all()` to send array of promises to GCF and await for all outstanding work/tasks to complete. Console log is not showing errors. I am trying to find out if I am doing the right implementation.

```
    exports.ObserveProposals = functions.database.ref("/proposals/{jobid}/{propid}").onWrite((event) => {
        const jobid = event.params.jobid;
        const userId = event.params.propid;
        const promises = [];
        const isinvitation = event.data.child("isinvitation").val();

        if (!isinvitation) {
            return userRef = admin.database().ref(`users/${userId}/proposals/sent`);
            if (event.data.exists() && !event.data.previous.exists()) {
                return userRef.child(jobid).set({
                    timestamp: admin.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
                });
            } else if (!event.data.exists() && event.data.previous.exists()) {
                return userRef.child(jobid).remove();
            }
        promises.push(userRef);
        }
        return collectionRef = admin.database().ref(`/jobs/${jobid}`).once('value').then(snapshot => {
        if (snapshot.val() !== null) {
          return countRef = collectionRef.child("proposals").transaction(current => {
            if (event.data.exists() && !event.data.previous.exists()) {
              return (current || 0) + 1;
            } else if (!event.data.exists() && event.data.previous.exists()) {
              return (current || 0) - 1;
            }
          });
         }
         promises.push(collectionRef);
       });
       return Promise.all(promises);
});
```

Comment: Not sure what you're asking here.  If it works the way you expect and you're not seeing errors, then I suppose there's no problem, right?

Comment: The code below `return userRef = ...` will never be run because you're returning. I think you want `let userRef = ...`

Comment: Thank you for the advise, I answered my the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bellow function is working properly, array of promises is being sent to GCF and all tasks are executed.

```
exports.ObserveProposals = functions.database.ref("/proposals/{jobid}/{propid}").onWrite((event) => {
    const jobid = event.params.jobid;
    const userid = event.params.propid;
    const promises = [];
    let userRef = admin.database().ref(`users/${userid}/proposals`);
    let jobRef = admin.database().ref(`/jobs/${jobid}/proposals`);
    jobRef.once('value').then(snapshot => {
        if (snapshot.val() !== null) {
            jobRef.transaction(current => {
                if (event.data.exists() && !event.data.previous.exists()) {
                    return (current || 0) + 1;
                } else if (!event.data.exists() && event.data.previous.exists()) {
                    return (current || 0) - 1;
                }
            });
        }
    });
    promises.push(jobRef);
    if (event.data.exists() && !event.data.previous.exists()) {
        const isInvitation = event.data.child("isinvitation").val();
        if (!isInvitation) {
            return userRef.child(`/sent/${jobid}`).set({
                timestamp: admin.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
            });
        } else if (isInvitation) {
            return userRef.child(`/received/${jobid}`).set({
                timestamp: admin.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
            });
        }
    } else if (!event.data.exists() && event.data.previous.exists()) {
        const isInvitation = event.data.previous.child("isinvitation").val();
        if (!isInvitation) {
            return userRef.child(`/sent/${jobid}`).remove();
        }else if (isInvitation) {
            return userRef.child(`/received/${jobid}`).remove();
        }
    }
    promises.push(userRef);
    return Promise.all(promises);
});
```

Comment: When I return it like this I often get `Error serializing return value: TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON` even though the function runs and completes (seemingly) correctly. If I tack on a `.then(()=>{}).catch(console.error)` it seems to work though.